# Run Oracle Forms at the right side of the web-browser

Tags: right-to-left, oracleforms

I want to run Oracle Forms (10G) at right side of the web-browser. I tried to change form property but it didn't work. Is there a way to change the display?

Comment: What exactly you mean by _run Oracle Forms at the right side of web browser_?

Comment: thanks for fast replay i will put link for image of the problem
http://postimg.org/image/4f7d2zfhn/

Comment: See [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/953460?tstart=0) might be able to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but it didn't help first i didn't know where is css and i need clear steps to that.
 please if you can help it will be so kind from you.
i change the nls_lang=ARABIC_UNITED ARAB EMIRATES.AR8MSWIN1256  and nothing happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i done it by using form.cfg file at server at forms software  changing the width  at it thanks again for help

Answer (score 0):

u Can set the window position. means the x and y position of the window